# Treating idents as string in Rust macros

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a configuration struct with some top level properties which I would like to put in sections. I order to provide deprecation warnings I made the following macro

```
macro_rules! deprecated {
($config:expr, $old:ident, $section:ident, $new:ident) => {
    if $config.$old.is_some() {
        println!(
            "$old configuration option is deprecated. Rename it to $new and put it under the section [$section]",
        );

        &$config.$old
    } else {
        if let Some(section) = &$config.$section {
            &section.$new
        } else {
            &None
        }
    }
};
```

}

This doesn't seem to work as expected as the macro parameters aren't substituted inside a string. How can I change the macro to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `println!("{} configuration option is deprecated. Rename it to {} and put it under the section [{}]", $old, $new, $section);`

Comment: @AlexLarionov that won't work as well. I'm not looking to print the value of the struct section in `$config.$old`, I'm just trying to print `$old` as a literal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `stringify!` macro can turn an element into a string literal, and the `concat!` macro can concatenate several literals into a single string literal:

```
println!(
    concat!(
        stringify!($old),
        " configuration option is deprecated. Rename it to ",
        stringify!($new),
        " and put it under the section [",
        stringify!($section),
        "]",
    )
);
```

[Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92c9c779637ccd5736909eb96c4025ef)